How to setup angular-ls on nvchad?
This is my lspconfig.lua:
local on_attach = require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").on_attach
local on_init = require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").on_init
local capabilities = require("nvchad.configs.lspconfig").capabilities

local lspconfig = require "lspconfig"
local servers = { "html", "cssls" }

-- lsps with default config
for _, lsp in ipairs(servers) do
  lspconfig[lsp].setup {
    on_attach = on_attach,
    on_init = on_init,
    capabilities = capabilities,
  }
end

lspconfig.angularls.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}
-- typescript
lspconfig.tsserver.setup {
  on_attach = on_attach,
  on_init = on_init,
  capabilities = capabilities,
}

When I enter a .ts file in my angular project I get an error: Client 1 quit with exit code 1 and signal 0
:LspInfo:

lsp.log last line:
[ERROR][2024-05-14 12:03:20] .../vim/lsp/rpc.lua:734    "rpc"   "ngserver"  "stderr"    "/home/shkoki/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/angular-language-server/node_modules/@angular/language-server/index.js:207893\n      throw new Error(Failed to resolve '${packageName}' with minimum version '${minVersion}' from  + JSON.stringify(probeLocations, null, 2));\n      ^\n\nError: Failed to resolve '@angular/language-service' with minimum version '15.0' from [\n  "/home/shkoki/dev/angular-calculator/node_modules"\n]\n    at resolveWithMinVersion (/home/shkoki/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/angular-language-server/node_modules/@angular/language-server/index.js:207893:13)\n    at resolveNgLangSvc (/home/shkoki/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/angular-language-server/node_modules/@angular/language-server/index.js:207944:14)\n    at main (/home/shkoki/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/angular-language-server/node_modules/@angular/language-server/index.js:207970:54)\n    at Object. (/home/shkoki/.local/share/nvim/mason/packages/angular-language-server/node_modules/@angular/language-server/index.js:207999:1)\n    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1358:14)\n    at Module._extensions..js (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1416:10)\n    at Module.load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1208:32)\n    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1024:12)\n    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1233:19)\n    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)\n\nNode.js v20.13.1\n"
▶ npm -g list
/home/shkoki/.nvm/versions/node/v20.13.1/lib
├── @angular/language-server@17.3.2
├── @angular/language-service@17.3.8
├── corepack@0.28.0
└── npm@10.5.2

I tried this as well but no result:
lspconfig.angularls.setup {}

Did you ever figure this out :)? I have a similar problem now  (although I use a mono-repo so the config may be a bit different).

@iMe switched to kickstart.nvim and it works fine there, never actually made it to work on nvchad
